# Spring batch header validation

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I'm new of spring batch and now I'm working on my first batch that should read from some flat files (.csv) and save some records on the database. I just want to upload those files for which I know the track. For example the track that i have to load is the following:

```
a;b;c
1;1;1
2;2;2
3;3;3
```

Then the track that i want to load is **a;b;c**. Many times, however, come some track with different track like:

```
b;a;c
1;1;1
2;2;2
3;3;3

a;b2;c
1;1;1
2;2;2
3;3;3
```

that I don't want to load. To solve it I'm thinking to generate a code from my track(a;b;c), and check each file header to load with this code, if the code doesn't correspond then I don't load the file.

a;b;c ---> 100

b;a;c ---> 200

a;b2;c---> 250

Now I want to ask you if this is the correct way to do, and others What is the function that allow me to generate an unique code for a string withuot collision?. Is the hash code useful for this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18517983/spring-batch-validate-header-lines-in-input-csv-file-and-skip-the-file-if-it-i/18519742#18519742

Comment: I saw that discussion but I would want some suggestion on the way to validate